# Infinite loading - return back to page number and scrolled item

Tags: javascript

Basically, I'm changing our current category page from pagination to infinite loading.

Everything works as it should, but my issue is returning back to the correct page and product.

This is currently my JS for loading the products

```
            $(document).on('click', '.page-next a', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();

                var self = $(this),
                    loadparent = self.parents('.ajax-load');

                setTimeout(function () { $(loadparent).fadeOut(); }, 700);

                $('.ajaxLoaderOverlay').addClass('show');

                    var url = $(this).data('url');

                    $.ajax({
                        url: url,
                        method: 'POST',
                        dataType: 'html',
                        success: function (data) {

                            $('.mid-content').append(data);
                            $('.ajaxLoaderOverlay').removeClass('show');

                        }
                    });

            });
```

I'm tracking the scrolling using a session storage

```
            $(window).scroll(function () {
                //set scroll position in session storage
                sessionStorage.scrollPos = $(window).scrollTop();

                console.log(sessionStorage);
            });
            var init = function () {
                //return scroll position in session storage
                $(window).scrollTop(sessionStorage.scrollPos || 0)
            };
            window.onload = init;
```

These work fine, but when a second page is loaded the window just scrolls to the bottom of the first page and never loads the correct page.

I know i will probably need to capture the page number, but a little unsure on how to do this.

any advice or suggestions would be great

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of saving the scroll of the single page as scalar, you can save the entire object with `JSON.stringify` and retrieve the information with `JSON.parse`.
You just have to memorize the current page somehow (I added some suggestions in the comments of the code).

```
/*
Retrive currentPage either from
    - url
    - session
    - global variabile (if you are using ajax - see also pjax to push state)
*/
currentPage = 0;    // to be changed

$(window).scroll(function () {
    var scrollPages = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.scrollPages);
    scrollPages = typeof scrollPages === "object" ? scrollPages : {};
    var scrollPos = $(window).scrollTop();
    scrollPages[currentPage] = scrollPos;
    //set scroll pages position in session storage
    sessionStorage.setItem('scrollPages', JSON.stringify(scrollPages));
    console.log(sessionStorage);
});
var init = function () {
    //return scroll position in session storage
    var scrollPages = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.scrollPages);
    scrollPages = typeof scrollPages === "object" ? scrollPages : {};
    $(window).scrollTop(scrollPages[currentPage] || 0)
};
window.onload = init;
```